# how to add offset for Poisson-GPR using GPML package?

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, matlab, gaussian-process, offset

I'm using the popular GPML package in MATLAB for both Poisson and NB regression. Is there any way to add offset as easily as glmfit()?
Specifically, assume there are N obesrvations, I want $\log(\mu)=\text{offset}+f(x)$, where $f(x)\sim GP$ and $\text{offset}\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Ortherwise, I guess I have to modify the likelihood function manually, which would be tedious...

**EDIT**

With the help of the package author, Hannes Nickisch, I finnaly find an easy way to do it. Moreover, modifying the likelihood function is not very tedious. See my answers below.

Comment: offset means intercept, right?

Comment: yes, fixed shifts/intercepts for each observations, as in glm. Basically, for N observations I want log(\mu) = f(x) + offset, where f ~ GP and offset \in R^N.

Comment: (had to look up the glmfit docs to make sure I understood). You want what's called a "constant mean function" in GPland, which is implemented as "meanConst" in GPML it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately, meanConst is the scalar intercept for all observations, but what I want is a N-dim fixed shifting vector for all observations. Yes it is actually linear mean, as we can write the mean function as m(x) = [offset x]*[1 0]' to achieve zero mean with offset. But when optimizing the hyperparameters, I need to keep [1 0] fixed and only update covariance. Also, expanding x to be x* = [offset x] makes coding covariance kernel unclear, since we want K(x_i,x_j), but not K(x*_i, x*_j)...

Comment: OK got it now; probably to account for differing period lengths or smth. From reading the docs, I don't see a standard way to implement it. But there is hope if we can implement a meanFunction whose hyperparams we can fix to 1 rather than optimizing. Not a GPML user but I don't see an easy way to fix hyperparams scanning the docs.

Comment: Please add extra information in the comments to the post, we want one coherent post with all necessary information, few people will read comments, and comments can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

**method 2: use meanDiscrete**
First, expand the predictor as `x_expand = [(1:N)' x];`, then use the 1st column for mean function snf 2nd column for covariance function...

```
maskMean = [true,false];
maskCov = [false,true];
m_raw = {@meanSum,{@meanConst,{'meanDiscrete',N}}};
c_raw = {@covSEiso};

m = {'meanMask',maskMean,m_raw};
c = {'covMask', {maskCov, c_raw{:}}};
```

To hold the offset fixed, we just need to clampsed prior on offset

```
prior.multi{1} = {@priorClampedMulti,struct('mean',2:(N+1))};
hyp1 = struct('mean', [0;offset], 'cov', [log(1);log(1)]);

options = struct('MaxIter',1000, 'Display', 'on');
im = {@infPrior,@infLaplace,prior};
hyp2 =  minimize_minfunc(hyp1,@gp,...
    options,im,m,c,likfunc,x_expand,y);
```

**method 2: modify the likelihood function**
Take the likPoisson.m for example. In their code, the `mu` is kind of confusing, it is actually the linear predictor, but not $E(Y)$. Since the code uses `lg = g(mu,link)` in line 34, and the special case should be `g(mu,'exp')` = `mu` = `lg`.

Keep this in mind, modify the function with a new input `offset`, and change all

```
lg = g(mu, link);
[lg,dlg,d2lg,d3lg] = g(mu,link);
```

to

```
lg_tmp = g(mu, link);
[lg_tmp,dlg,d2lg,d3lg] = g(mu,link);
lg = lg_tmp + offset;
```